# Webpages jump up to the top when auto post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, autopostback

I am having a problem when I mark some checkbox checked in a grid view, the page itself will jump back to the top instead of staying at the same position when auto post back. Here is how I set up my grid view:

```
<UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <!-- COLLAPSIBLE PANEL EXTENDER -->
                        <asp:Panel ID="pHeader1" runat="server" CssClass="cpHeader">
                            <!-- Collapsible panel extender header -->
                            <div class="form-group" style="background-color: #ffb848; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div style="float: left; color: White; padding: 5px 5px 0 0">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "categoryName") %>' runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <div style="float: right; color: White; padding: 5px 5px 0 0">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblHeaderText1" runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear: both"></div>
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <!-- Collapsible panel extender body -->
                        <asp:Panel ID="pBody1" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBodyText1" runat="server" />
                            <!-- Grid view to show products based on each category -->
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="998px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" DataKeyNames="id">
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCheckRow" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="650px" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="inventoryQuantity" HeaderText="Total Unit" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbQuantity" runat="server" Width="40" Text="0" OnTextChanged="tbQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCheckAmount" runat="server" ForeColor="#a94442"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>
                                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#ffb848" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#d8d8d8" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe1" runat="server" TargetControlID="pBody1" CollapseControlID="pHeader1"
                            ExpandControlID="pHeader1" Collapsed="true" TextLabelID="lblHeaderText1" CollapsedText="Show"
                            ExpandedText="Hide" CollapsedSize="0"
                            ScrollContents="false">
                        </asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                </ContentTemplate>
                </UpdatePanel>
```

I've added the update panel. So far from my research, I know that we should use update panel to prevent the page jump up when auto post back. However, mine does not work. Any guides?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` attribute of page `Directive`. See Sample below:

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Comment: if this solves you issue than please mark this as answer to your question.

Thanks

Comment: When I use this, the page flashes with each checkbox click.